# Open venue without "Open in the app.." popup

Tags: objective-c, foursquare

I´m currently working on an app where I need to open a foursquare venue in a webview after parsing for specific venue-ids. Almost everytime I open a link like

```
https://www.foursquare.com/v/4cd322529828b60c87e8d384
```

I get a popup saying I can download the foursquare app. This really ruins my navigation flow because if the user doesn´t like one venue he can request a new one but then getting another popup-window. It would be fine if the window would only appear once but not everytime. Is there a trick or can I disable "popups" in a webview or anything? Thx.

Comment: yeah, sure I checked out the api, that´s how I retrieve the ids. What do you mean by "use their api within your app"?

Comment: ...so basically I changed the user agent to firefox instead of iphone/ipad. The popup disappears and I get to see the desktop version. Is this """ok?""". From a legal standpoint?